# trying to align two divs to the center to begin at thesame position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two divs to the center and to begin at the same position using css

this is the inline style css code. The name of the first div is **container** and the name of the second div **descriptionarea**

```
#container {
            width: 60%;
            height: auto;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }

        .inner-container {
            min-height: 400px;
            display: inline-block;
            overflow-y: auto;
            border: 4px solid black;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }

        #chats-container {
            height: 70%;
            width: 60%;
            padding-top:5px;
            padding-left:5px;
        }

        #users-container {
            height: 70%;
            width: 22%;
            padding-top:5px;
            padding-left:5px;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
        border: 1px solid #f44c0e;
        color: #fff;
        background: tomato;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        }
        input[type=submit]:hover {
            background: #f44c0e;
        }

        textarea {
         width: 550px;
         height: 60px;
         font: normal 14px verdana;
         line-height: 30px;
         padding: 2px 10px;
         border: solid 1px #ddd;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        }


        .descriptionarea {
       min-width: 490px;
       position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        }

    .descriptionarea textarea{
    width: 490px;
    height: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    font: normal 14px verdana;

    }

    .descriptionarea span.namefortxtarea{
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    .descriptionarea span.buttonfortxtarea{
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

this is how I am calling/applying the two divs in html format
**first div**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="chats-container" class="inner-container">
    </div>
   <div id="users-container" class="inner-container">

    </div>
</div>
```

**second div**

```
<div class="descriptionarea">
    <textarea id="new-chat-input" ></textarea>
    <span class="buttonfortxtarea">
    <button class= "btn btn-mini description_submit" id="new-chat-button">Submit</button></span>
    </div>
```

I have tried applying to both divs but still the two divs is not aligned to the center and not beginning to the same position.

margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;

Comment: It will be tricky trying to centrally align 2 divs next to eachother - you'd be better off putting them both into a container and then centrally aligning the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the id attribute for div#container and replace it within .descriptionarea class and you wrap both divs with a parent div#container your divs will line up in the center.

```
<div id="container">
<div class="descriptionarea">
    <div id="chats-container" class="inner-container"></div>
    <div id="users-container" class="inner-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="descriptionarea">
    <textarea id="new-chat-input" ></textarea>
    <span class="buttonfortxtarea">
             <button class="btn btn-mini description_submit" id="new-chat-button">Submit</button>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you break it down further please. if possible add some more snippets

Comment: Here is an example that incorporates float rules and allows your HTML code to be a bit more responsive. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/n3ubxtv1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Flexbox, it supported all popular browsers, and please, use CamelCase notation or hyphens in class names.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is because of display: inline-block. You should try to use putting your blocks in one container and using float: left for the first and second div. And to delete display: inline-block

```
<div class = "center">
    <div id="chats-container" class="inner-container">
</div>
   <div id="users-container" class="inner-container">

</div>
</div>
<div class="descriptionarea">
    <textarea id="new-chat-input" ></textarea>
    <span class="buttonfortxtarea">
    <button class= "btn btn-mini description_submit" id="new-chat-button">Submit</button></span>
    </div>
</div> 



 .inner-container {
            min-height: 400px;
           float: left;
            overflow-y: auto;
            border: 4px solid black;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }

.descriptionarea {
       min-width: 490px;
       position: relative;
       margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        float: left;
        }
```